# Generate EAN 13 barcode with Zen Barcode Rendering Framework

Tags: c#, barcode

Does anyone know how to generate EAN 13 or EAN 8 barcode using Zen Barcode Rendering Framework? There is no documentation, i also read test project but also there not have example how generate EAN 13.

This code work good but this is for `Code128` i need `EAN 13`.

```
Zen.Barcode.Code128BarcodeDraw barcode = Zen.Barcode.BarcodeDrawFactory.Code128WithChecksum;
        var barcodeImage = barcode.Draw(val, 60);
        var resultImage = new Bitmap(barcodeImage.Width, barcodeImage.Height);
```

Comment: Please have a look at the below link might be useful http://www.keepautomation.com/guide/csharp_barcode_generator.html

Comment: This is comercial

Answer (score 0):

EAN 8 and EAN 13 are both derived from the UPC barcode standard and therefore will not work with a Code128 framework.

Try:

```
Zen.Barcode.CodeEan13BarcodeDraw barcode = Zen.Barcode.BarcodeDrawFactory.CodeEan13WithChecksum;
```

Or:

```
Zen.Barcode.CodeEan8BarcodeDraw barcode = Zen.Barcode.BarcodeDrawFactory.CodeEan8WithChecksum;
```